VueJS: Tracking the order of child components in a parent slot at run time
I have a custom component where the parent and an array of child components are tightly coupled and there is a "backdoor" communication between the parent and child components using the provide-inject feature provided by vue.
In the parent component, I would like to keep track of the child components in the order they are defined in the slot.
I know that on mounted, the child components are instantiated in the order they are defined. However, at runtime, a child component might be inserted in between first child component and second child component for example. The question is how do I find out the updated order of the child components in the parent slot?
I saw in the vue devtools, it can recognise the order of child and nested components in the Components tab and show it in a tree layout. How can I achieve something like that?
Here is the example code
https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-pkqhkv?file=src%2FApp.vue
In the above example, if you click prev and next, it should show Slide 1 and Slide 3 as expected because Slide 2 is toggled 'off', but when you toggle on Slide 2, the order goes into 1, 3, 2 which is not what I want. The order should be 1, 2 and 3.
Obviously, the implementation of providing each child with a numbered index is not reliable as they can be registered at different times, therefore I want to implement differently where I can know the current order of the Child components at any given time.

Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. This depends on a way in which the order is changed dynamically. If there's v-for, you can track the array and keys that determine what it renders

Even your parent/child components are strongly coupled you better don't propagate the slide visibility state to the children. That's not a good design, too much leaking of the slide state. Make all slide logic inside the parent (a good design and encapsulation).
VUE SFC PLAYGROUND
Parent.vue
<script setup>

import { ref, useSlots, watch, computed } from 'vue';

// the current component index
const current = ref(0);

const slots = useSlots();
// collect all slot child components
const $children = computed(() => slots.default().filter(vnode => vnode.type.render)); // remove all non-component vnodes
// watch for deletion of the current component and move to the next one
watch(() => $children.value.length, length => current.value < length || next(current.value - 1));


function prev(idx = current.value) {
  if(--idx < 0) idx = $children.value.length - 1;
  current.value = idx;
}

function next(idx = current.value) {
  if(++idx >= $children.value.length) idx = 0;
  current.value = idx;
}

defineExpose({
  prev,
  next,
});
</script>

<template>
  <section>
    <div>$children.length: {{ $children.length }}, current: {{ current }}</div>
    <component :is="() => $children.filter((_, idx)=> idx === current)" />
  </section>
</template>


App.vue
<script setup>
import Parent from './Parent.vue';
import Child from './Child.vue';
import { ref } from 'vue';

const toggleSlide2 = ref(false);
const toggleSlide3 = ref(true);
const parent = ref();

</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <section>
      <button @click="parent.prev()">Prev</button>
      <button @click="parent.next()">Next</button>
      <button @click="toggleSlide2 = !toggleSlide2">Toggle Slide 2</button>
       <button @click="toggleSlide3 = !toggleSlide3">Toggle Slide 3</button>
    </section>

    <Parent ref="parent">
      <Child>
        <h1>Slide 1</h1>
      </Child>
      <Child v-if="toggleSlide2">
        <h1>Slide 2</h1>
      </Child>
      <Child v-if="toggleSlide3">
        <h1>Slide 3</h1>
      </Child>
    </Parent>
  </div>
</template>



thanks for the reply but the parent and child is designed to have a strong coupling

@icube yes, have a strong coupling, provide/inject, no problem. but having the slide mechanism leaking into the children is a bad design imho. no need in this

@icube i've updated the answer to clarify that

thanks for the clarification, but the reason for my question is to ask if there is a way to track the order of the children from the parent as declared in the slot, without having the child to explicitly set the order. if i have the child to explicitly set the order, i wouldn't have asked the question in the first place as I know i can get the information easily

@icube what's wrong with my solution? you have a slide logic that works as asked

nothing wrong with your solution and it works yes, but my question is how to track the order of the children in a parent slot in the order they were declared in the slot, without explicitly providing an order key.

Continuation of the First answer.
Try passing Child component this way. The drawback is need to add html as string and bind as v-html
<parent-component :slotsArray="slotsArray">
  <button @click="addSlotToIndex(2, 'Item 21')">Add Item on 2nd 
     Index</button>
  <button @click="addSlotToIndex(0, 'Item 00')">Add Item on 1st 
     Index</button>
   <template v-for="(s) in slotsArray">
    <template :slot="s.name">
      <child-component :inner-html="s.child" :key="s.i"></child-component>
    </template>
  </template>
</parent-component>

Child Component
<template>
   <component :is="tag">
     <slot>
       <div v-html="innerHtml"></div>
     </slot>
   </component></template>



   <script>
  export default {
    props: {
       innerHtml: { type: String, default: '' },
       tag: { type: String, default: 'div' }
    }
  };</script>

NB: May not be useful if the child component is complicated with more elements

Passed slots as an array of objects, passed inner element content as value inside the object. added new slots using array splicing. You can use v-html or other methods if the child component having more elements
Parent Component
<template>
   <div>
     <slot></slot>
     <ul>
        <li v-for="(s,i) in slotsArray" :key="i">
            <slot :name="s.name"></slot>
        </li>
     </ul>
 </div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      slotsArray: { type: Array, default: null }
    }
  };</script>

Parent Component Usage and adding slots
<template>
  <div>
     <!-- Parent Component -->
     <parent-component :slotsArray="slotsArray">
         <button @click="addSlotToIndex(2, 'Item 21')">Add Item on 2nd 
            Index</button>
         <button @click="addSlotToIndex(0, 'Item 00')">Add Item on 1st 
            Index</button>
         <template v-for="(s) in slotsArray">
             <template :slot="s.name">
                <p :key="s.i">{{s.child}}</p>
             </template>
         </template>
  </parent-component></div></template>

<script>
import ParentComponent from './views/parent-child- 
    slots/ParentComponent.vue';

export default {
    name: 'App',
    components: { ParentComponent },
    data () {
        return {
            slotsArray: [
                {
                    name: 'slota',
                    child: 'Item 1'
                },
                {
                    name: 'slotb',
                    child: 'Item 2'
                },
                {
                    name: 'slotc',
                    child: 'Item 3'
                }
            ],
            addSlotToIndex (idx, value) {
                this.slotsArray.splice(idx, 0, {
                    name: idx > 0 ? this.slotsArray[idx - 1].name + 'a' : 
                     this.slotsArray[0].name + 'a',
                   child: value
            });
        }
    };
}};


thanks for the reply but I would prefer not to have to pass an array as a prop because I want the consumer to be able to pass in a template in the Child component. you can have a look in the first post where I shared the link to the example code
